# What kind of action does it takes to sprout wings with wings of heaven?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, sorcerer

pretty explicit.

I am talking about this :

> Wings of Heaven (Su): At 9th level, you can sprout feathery wings and fly for a number of minutes per day equal to your sorcerer level, with a speed of 60 feet and good maneuverability. This duration does not need to be consecutive, but it must be used in 1 minute increments.

The celestial bloodline allows one to sprout wings, but doesn't specify if it takes a standard, swift, move, or free action. Does anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 5):

It's a Standard action.

As per the [Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat)

> Using a supernatural ability is usually a standard action (unless defined otherwise by the ability's description). Its use cannot be disrupted, does not require concentration, and does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

This means in a single round one could sprout the wings as a Standard and then fly 60' as Move...but couldn't both sprout them and attack.